# R function for a timer with a beep

Tags: beginner, r, timer

I wrote a quick timer function that depends on the `beepr` package to provide the sound effect at the end of the time.  I've never used a while-loop before, so I don't know if there's a more elegant way to write this (i.e., one that doesn't require repeating the same line of code twice?).  I'd appreciate knowing if there is a better way:

```
timer <- function(interval, units) {
require(beepr)
t0 <- Sys.time()
stopwatch <- round(as.double(difftime(Sys.time(), t0, u = units)))
while(stopwatch < interval){
  stopwatch <- round(as.double(difftime(Sys.time(), t0, u = units)))
  }
beep(2)
}

timer(5, "secs")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid repeating code, you could have used:

```
done <- FALSE
while(!done){
  done <- round(as.double(difftime(Sys.time(), t0, u = units))) >= interval
}
```

Note however that a `for` loop is quite taxing on your CPU. Instead, you should use the friendlier `Sys.sleep` function. It takes a number of seconds as input:

```
timer <- function(num_sec) {
   Sys.sleep(num_sec)
   if (require(beepr)) beep(2) else message("DONE!")
}
```

Notice how I improved your code regarding the use of `require`, since you had not accounted for the possibility that your user does not have the `beepr` package installed. If you want to make the `beepr` package a requirement, then calling `library(beepr)` is prefered to `require(beepr)`, the blog here https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ offers a nice explanation.

If you absolutely want your function to allow to pass "minutes", "days", etc. (though I would stay away from it), you can do:

```
timer <- function(interval, units = c("secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")) {
   units <- match.arg(units)
   num_sec <- interval * switch(units, secs = 1, mins = 60, hours = 3600,
                                       days = 86400, weeks = 604800)
   Sys.sleep(num_sec)
   if (require(beepr)) beep(2) else message("DONE!")
}
```